# can't return motionEvent.action_up

Tags: android, events, touch

please see my code

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
         Log.e("mainClass",""+ event.getY( ));
     manager.setNewX((int)event.getX());
     manager.setNewY((int)event.getY());
     log("action = "+event.getAction());
     manager.doTouchEvent(event.getAction());
     return false;

}
```

when i pressed on field - i see coordinates and  action ( `event.getAction()`). I see what log returned me 0 (`action.down`). But when i leave my finger from screen i not see `event.action_up`. Can any one explain me why i can't get `actio_up`

p.s. doTouchEvent - function which used in other class.  doTouchEvent(int event);

p.s2 hello everyone :) can't set this to first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define onTouchEvent() for your custom view try calling it for the super view.

```
return super.onTouchEvent(event);.
```

Comment: not working (( after if - test's  i see what only action_down work . Other action's not working :(

Comment: i fixed it.. can't understand but when using "if" - my code not work , but when im using switch - than all works perfectly . Thanks  u code helped me too.

Answer (score 1):

Just return true. **do not return false**.

Answer (score 0):

After I insert return super.onTouchEvent(event); at the end of the method (onTouchEvent must return a value) your code works for me, when I put it in a blank main activity.

You should probably return true instead of breaking in those cases because you are responding to the event.
[Android ACTION_UP even never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880284/android-action-up-even-never-called)