# Android ACTION_UP even never called

Tags: android, touch-event

I'm trying to make a small android Jump and Run game but my problem is that i can't configure the  event ACTION_UP right. Here my Code:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        Log.d("OTE", "down"); 
        touchDownTrue = true;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        Log.d("OTE", "UP"); 
        touchDownTrue = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

the case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is never called and i don't know why, the same happens if i use ACTION_CANCEL

Comment: Do you get a motion event at all? If you do get a motion event then what type is it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After I insert `return super.onTouchEvent(event);` at the end of the method (onTouchEvent must return a value) your code works for me, when I put it in a blank main activity.

You should probably `return true` instead of breaking in those cases because you are responding to the event.